# Get-Service shows different results when run directly on server and when run remotely via Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

when I execute:

$serviceName = "Tanium Client"
Get-Service $serviceName

Directly On Server

it gives:

Status   Name               DisplayName

---

Running  Tanium Client      Tanium Client

but when I run it remotely from another server via Invoke-Command it does not shows Tanium Service.

Error:
Cannot find any service with service name 'Tanium Client'.

But if I look for any other service it gives me the result (tried with couple more services but not all) :

it returns the service

does any body have any idea or solution for this

Hi,

when I execute:

$serviceName = "Tanium Client"
Get-Service $serviceName

Directly On Server

it gives:

Status   Name               DisplayName

---

Running  Tanium Client      Tanium Client

but when I run it remotely from another server via Invoke-Command it does not shows Tanium Service.

$computer = ""
$scriptblock = {Get-Service "Tanium Client"}

```
$service = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -Credential $c -ScriptBlock $scriptblock

if ($service) {
    Write-Host "Tanium service status" $service.Status
} else {
    Write-Host "Tanium service is not found"
}
```

Error:
Cannot find any service with service name 'Tanium Client'.

But if I look for any other service it gives me the result (tried with couple more services but not all) :

Example:

$scriptblock = {Get-Service "Themes"}

```
$service = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -Credential $c -ScriptBlock $scriptblock

if ($service) {
    Write-Host "service status" $service.Status
    $service
} else {
    Write-Host "service is not found"
}
```

service status Running

Status   Name               DisplayName                            PSComputerName

---

Running  Themes             Themes

does any body have any idea or solution for this

(I also tried Enter-Pssession and went to server, Ran Get-Service T* it does not returns the Tanium server in the list of services starting with T, but when I do get-Service T* on server directly it does returns Tanium in the list)

Comment: my intuition tells me the matter is in the gap. Apparently you need to additionally escape the quotes

Comment: Please try to adjust the formatting of your query as it's currently difficult to understand the question or see which bits of text refer to commands being run, which are errors returned, and which are you providing information.

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).